# WPF/XAML vs MVC Paradigm: flawed in the very fundamental design

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

In MVC a model can have multiple views, in WPF a XAML code-behind model is tight to 1 single XAML (view) isn't WPF/XAML flawed from the start in respect to MVC ?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend looking at MVVM for use with WPF.

You're comparing MVC with Windows Forms to WPF with code behind - which is comparing an architectural pattern to a technology (without using a pattern).  This is an unfair comparison.

I wrote a series on [MVVM starting from a Windows Forms perspective](http://reedcopsey.com/talks/from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm/) that may help with understanding this.  You'll find that the separation of View and ViewModel possible with WPF is far cleaner and simpler to implement than the Controller of MVC.  It actually allows even more decoupled architectures with less implementation work.

Comment: I heard about MVVM which is a variant of MVC but why isn't xaml done right from the start ?

Comment: @user310291: It IS done right from the start.  It's VERY flexible.  That's part of its power.  You're comparing an architectural pattern of usage (which is very tough to get right in Windows Forms) to an underlying technology.  It's not a clean comparison.

Comment: @user310291: XAML makes life easy to make very decoupled apps.

Comment: MVC is not linked to Windows Form it is a smalltalk pattern originally. The fact that "ViewModel
Exposes Model to View via DataBinding
Exposes Logic via ICommand" doesn't prevent that there should be multiple views/XAML allowed per single ViewModel.

Comment: Decoupling but in a limited way compared to original MVC.

Comment: @user310291: You can have an unlimited number of Views per ViewModel.  The ViewModel is 100% independent of the View layer.  MVC is MORE coupled than MVVM.  The Controller in MVC needs quite a bit of information and needs to be written for a specific View technology.  In MVVM, the ViewModel is completely technology independent... There should be NO references to UI class/technology in the ViewModel in MVVM.

Comment: @user310291: I recommend reading through my series - I think you have a misunderstanding of how MVVM works.

Comment: @user310291: For example, I recently worked on a project where one of the requirements was to be able to swap out any View in the project, at runtime, with one customized to a specific customer.  In MVVM, this is EASY - you just change a DataTemplate at runtime that loads a different View.  This was supporting multiple Views with a single ViewModel.

Comment: @Reed and why do I have to use yet another pattern instead of just using XAML if XAML was designed the right way to be one of a view collection for a model ? Why do I have to get a headache to do something like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/writing-cross-platform-xaml-applications.aspx just because of the way XAML model  has been tighted to one single View.

Comment: @user310291: XAML is not "the view collection for a model".  It's a way of defining user interfaces.  XAML should be compared to "Windows Forms" or "MFC" or "SmallTalk UI Framework" - MVC should be compared to MVVM....   As an aside- the "headache" you're describing and linked to is about reusing the same codebase against **three completely different platforms and technologies** - That was impossible in MVC.  Each platform would require a completely custom Controller, as well as a rewrite of the View from scratch...

Comment: That was impossible in MVC ? And why ? I read the original paper it's about having the model as first class citizen the views don't matter. Whereas in WPF/XAML the view is primary citizen and the model is a slave of the view and so you have to create yet another framework to have this decoupling.

Comment: @user310291: The "Model" is identical in MVC and MVVM.  That's true - the "views' don't matter in relation to the model.  It's the "Controller" that I'm talking about.  The Controller in MVC has a strong coupling to the technology/platform used.  In MVVM, the ViewModel does NOT.  Here, the Model AND the ViewModel are technology/platform independent, so the only thing requiring customization is (potentially) the View.  As that link you showed demonstrates, even teh View can potentially be reused, too...

Comment: You keep mentioning MVVM as good pattern which I agree but my very point is we wouldn't need to craft MVVM ourself if XAML was designed as a real View in MVC or MVVM if you prefer :)

Comment: @user310291: I guess the problem with that is there are times when you want construct a UI without using a pattern.  For example, MVVM/MVC/MVP is really not valid if you're making a reusable custom control.  It doesn't always make sense to use the architectural pattern, which is why I'm glad it's not built-in.  That being said, MVVM has nearly no overhead or framework requirements on top of "standard" wpf, so in a sense, it's built-in, but built-in as an option.

Comment: MVVM/MVC/MVP is really not valid if you're making a reusable custom control. ? I really don't agree with you : the concept of model / view / controller is something unviversal. And what I am asking is about a 1-N relationship between model and Views not just 1-1 relationship so having the 1st one doesn't hurt the second simple case. The first principle in software Architecture is K.I.S.S principle this 1-N relationship is simple much more straightwordward expressiveness implementation of MVC or other MVCish implementation that yet another custom MVCish framework that add yet another layer.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

In MVC you state that a model can have multiple views, which is true. However, each view would have its own controller.

In MVVM a model can have multiple views, and in this case each may have their own view model.

However, in practical terms, if a ViewModel does not have any concepts that are highly specific to a certain view, it is entirely possible to re-use view models. In fact, I wrote an article on cross-platform XAML applications where I re-used code between three apps, one on WP7, one in Silverlight, the other WPF:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/writing-cross-platform-xaml-applications.aspx

The views for each were very different, however I was able to re-use both the models AND the view models for all three apps.

Comment: Very interesting as your very example shows that you have to ressort to do tricks to do what should be obvious if MVC paradigm was respected from the start in the XAML design !

Comment: Tricks? erm ... what tricks? I have been creating UI apps for 10 years, and have used MVC, MVP and MVVM. Personally I like MVVM for its simplicity and testability. I have used MVVM in WinForms as well as WPF. It really is a goo and flexible pattern.

Comment: And why isn't it integrated right in XAML instead of having to build yet another layer of framework ?

Comment: Sharing assembly code between WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone: quite impractical for big projects : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848487/sharing-assembly-code-between-wpf-silverlight-and-windows-phone-quite-impractic

Comment: Also on my kind of project I need more than just styling on different platforms I have to create completely different kind of widgets. It's a problem that shouldn't be if XAML was designed the right way that is true separation of XAML-View and of model.

Answer (score 0):

WPF/XAML is a technology, and MVC is design pattern, it's good when technology is not limiting you to a specific pattern, and allows developer to choose what pattern to use. Same as programing languages allow's you to use any design pattern.

You can use MVC, MVP, MVVM, or YourMegaPattern with XAML\WPF. Technology should be above patterns, it's frameworks that are usually bound to a specific pattern.

For example you can take ASP .NET techology, and MVC framework based on it.